# Server to Client response asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a scenario where there're two servers. A web application in server 1 gets a value from a real physical device. The physical device sends a value say Time = 60. This value is sent to  server 2 where another web application is hosted. In server 2, the web pages receives the value and displays a label counting down from 60(received value from server 1) to 0 displaying to the clients. The response from server 1 to web application in server 2 is asynchronous. Any direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance

**In web application in server 1, i've done to post "timer value of 60" to web application(../Test/Default.aspx) in server 2**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = Post.Data("server2/Test/Default.aspx", new NameValueCollection() {
        { "GameStart", "True" },
        { "Timer", "60" },      
        { "GameStop", "True" },
        { "WinningNumber", "35" }         
    });
}

public static class Post
{
    public static byte[] Data(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
    {
        byte[] response = null;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Now in the server 2, i've done as below to get the request and I am getting the value as well. but it doesn't display the value in the lblTimer as i believe the page is already rendered. How can i display the timer in label**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {         
        if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {
            string Timer = Request.Form["Timer"];
            lblTimer.Text = Timer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this your scenario then what is your question?

Comment: :) sorry about that..what should i do to asynchronously post the "time" value from web application hosted in server 1 to web application hosted in server 2 and display the count down in client side in web appication hosted in server 2 accordingly

Comment: can't understand buddy, scenario is explained now explain you question..

Comment: so you want to communicate between two servers..

Comment: actually between two web applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question is really about updating a value on a web page that is already rendered.

Take a look at using [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). The tutorials provided there will help you with your specific problem.

On server 2 you would create a hub that is in connection with your web clients and whenever server 1 sends an update to server 2, you would trigger a method in this hub to push out an update to your rendered web pages.

The web page with your timer label on it will contain a JavaScript event handler that can be triggered from the server. The JavaScript will then be responsible for updating the label on your page, even after the page has been rendered.  Take a look at the [Stock Ticker Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20) on the SignalR website as it is similar to what you are trying to achieve; it also sounds like your situation is not even as complicated as the stock picker.

Answer (score 0):

Server2 is going to return a rendered HTML page to server1. This will not update the HTML rendered by server1 unless you write some code...

You would need to parse the HTML returned to pull out the data required and then display it in your page where you need it.  If you have any control over server2, then it would be better to call a web service together this info rather than a web page.

Also, assuming that your requirement is more complicated than stated, as otherwise server1 could just handle the counter after the post to server2, which I assume just starts a game?

Comment: Thanks paddy for the response, actually i've worked around through the code mentioned above and i get the value 60 in timer string in web page(server 2)..but i can't get that to display in the label..Moreover, I might have a continiously running service in Server 1 rather than an web application